# Cannot access my web server

Tags: asp.net, dns, ip, crystal-reports-2008, nameservers

I just subscribed for shared hosting plan on ASPHOSTCENTRAL. I changed my Domain settings and pointed to the name servers as they said(10hrs ago). Since then I've been trying to access my website's default page but I can't. It prompts me to enter a User name and a password.

When I asked the help desk, they said it's working on their end and they can see the default web page.

This is an ASP .Net web application (3.5 framework) with Crystal reports (V12) and MS SQL server database.

The support team said when I try to ping ebolamedia.ae(my domain) then I should get 208.43.160.193 but on my end I see 174.37.255.233.

I don't understand what is wrong. Can someone help me... I can't access my FTP too.

Comment: there's a reason the word 'server' is in the site name  'serverfault' ....

Comment: I understand that Mitch. I did post the same thing over there too. But I believe that there are more expert over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just check it now and see 208.43.160.193, so probably **you** are the problem, and its probably the dns cache on your computer.

There maybe a dns cache from your web browser or a dns cache from your computer. To clear the dhs cache of your computer open a dos prompt, (`start | run | cmd`) and run

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and probably is going to reread the dns and works.

Alternative open your **windows/system32/drivers/host** file with text pad and check or add manually the correct ip for your web address, just to make it play and you make your work until all dns flush and clear.

Comment: I have tried clearing my browser cache, system DNS cache, restarted my PC and every network device I have at home. But still it is taking me somewhere else. I asked some of my friends who lives in my area but still no difference. Maybe it is cached by my ISP because we have only one ISP in our country. Is it possible if it could be cached by my ISP ?

Comment: @Amandeep yes its possible, this is usually 24h cache. Use the host file on the windows/system32/drivers to change the ip manually until your cache change. To find the ip, just make on command prompt a "ping  ebolamedia.ae"

Comment: I just edited my hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and now the file has : 127.0.0.1 genuine.microsoft.com
127.0.0.1 mpa.one.microsoft.com
127.0.0.1 sls.microsoft.com
208.43.160.195 ns13.asphostserver.com -DNS 1 (provided for my domain)
208.43.125.63 ns2.asphostserver.com -DNS 2 (provided for my domain)
208.43.160.193 www.ebolamedia.ae But still it is pointing to some other server and prompts to enter a user name and password.

Comment: @amandeep Yes I see that now that show to me www.ebolamedia.ae -> 174.37.255.233 they have mix up again.(and ask to me also for password). I make a report for you here, http://www.dnsvalidation.com/reports/4ed8e2297d79ee5bd6000016

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSaini From the report show the correct ip, but there is a doublication on the servers on the "Identical NS Records" so there maybe they have mix up ! from your host and they have both ips. I think that you need again to ask from your host to fix that, or you if its possible to fix the dns file if you can access to it.

Comment: Thank you so much Aristos. Before taking any action I would like to wait for it to be 24 hrs (4 hrs left) so the Cache get cleared. I will get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSaini From the report the dns have errors ! Some must fix them and if you do not control the dns records, then you should open a ticket to your hosting company to make it for you.

Comment: Dear Aristos, I have my own domain where I specified the DNS name servers that they provided. Can I change the DNS to something else and then change it back to their name servers ? Would this help?

Comment: http://www.dnsvalidation.com/reports/4ed8e8327d79ee236000000a#ns

Comment: Aristos, I can now see my home page. It was cached by my ISP.